# JHipster show on start the login dialog instead the home page with checking of the rights

Tags: angularjs, angular, authentication, jhipster

i'm using the [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) framework for make angular app with java spring boot backend, now i have integrate my own angular app with the defaults "administrator" features of  jhipster, it's work fine and now i'm tring to make some customization of the angular frontend.

I'm found some difficulty to make these three things, without modify to much code of the default jhipster project:

1) **On start of the jhipster project, i want to see the login default dialog of jhipster instead the jhipster home**, i have tried with many suggestion on the internet but i failed, i make a brute force solution, by emulate a click on the "access" button on the loading of the home page, but i don't like that solution. And i want the user always redirect to the login dialog popup until a succesfully login.

2) **Only administrator can access and view the default application jhipster. The user can acces only to my angular app**, so i want to intercept a control to check if the login user not have administration rights he can only see angular modules under my app root path e.g. "http://xxxxxxxx/myapp/*". if is administrator he can acess everywhere. So if i acces like user and try to go to the home jhipster module on the url "http://xxxxxxxx/*" i make redirect the user to my main page app "http://xxxxxxxx/myapp/".

3) **When a session in ended , any call to the app must redirect to the login dialog module until a new succesfuly login.**

The code except for the integration of my angular app just a welcome page for make it simple at the url "http://xxxxxxxx/myapp/" is the same of the default last jhipster with angular 5.

ty in advance for any help.